# how to solve No overload matches this call error typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hey i'm new to typescript and i get error for the **zoom** like in the picture below

[error overload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCZXj.png)

here's the code do you guys know how to solve this error?

```
function ImageCroper({ image, setCropedImage }) {
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState<number | string>(1);
  const [coord, setCoord] = useState<any>(null);
  const onCropComplete = useCallback((croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
    setCoord(croppedAreaPixels);
  }, []);

  const cutImage = () => {
    cropImage64(image, coord.x, coord.y, coord.width, coord.height).then(
      (croppedImage) => {
        setCropedImage(croppedImage);
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="cropper">
      <div className="cropper-container">
        <Cropper
          image={image}
          crop={crop}
          zoom={zoom}
          cropShape="round"
          showGrid={false}
          aspect={1}
          onCropChange={setCrop}
          onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
          onZoomChange={setZoom}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="cropper-controls">
        <input
          className="cropper-zoom-range"
          type="range"
          value={zoom}
          min={1}
          max={3}
          step={0.01}
          aria-labelledby="Zoom"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setZoom(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input type="button" onClick={() => cutImage()} value="cut" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i'm new to typescript i try to give the zoom type number but i get another error for** e.target.value** Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.

what i need to change or to add to solve this problem?

Comment: `setZoom(+e.target.value)` or `setZoom(e.target.valueAsNumber)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your source code, specifically the file where you declare your Cropper component, it's hard to be absolutely certain, but it looks like the problem is most likely that the props for your Cropper component are typed so that zoom is an optional number:

```
type CropperProps = {
  // other props
  zoom?: number;
}

function Cropper(props: CropperProps) {
  // component code
}
```

In your ImageCropper component, however, you have your zoom state, which is typed as `string | number`. You're then passing the value of this state into your Cropper component as its zoom prop, and TypeScript is giving you an error because you're trying to assign a number or string to a property that can only be a number.

There are two ways that you could fix this:

1. Change the type of your zoom prop in your Cropper component to be `number | string`:

```
type CropperProps = {
  // other props
  zoom?: number | string;
}
```

2. Change your zoom state to only be a number:

```
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState<number>(1);
```

Depending on how you're using your zoom prop, each of these changes could have trickle down effects, and cause small typing errors elsewhere in your code. If you go with the second option here, make sure to also change the code where you are setting the zoom state:

```
onChange={(e) => {
  setZoom(e.target.valueAsNumber);
}}
```

**How I Got Here**

Getting a handle on these kinds of errors can be tricky when you're first learning TypeScript. Make sure you read them carefully. In your case, the error said:

```
Type `string | number` is not assignable to type `number | undefined`
```

The error also specifically called out the property 'zoom' in your Cropper props. So that shows that you are assigning a value of type `string | number`, easily found in your code where you are declaring your zoom state, to your zoom prop in your Cropper component, and that is not the type your Cropper component is expecting for that prop.